# Add a play button to a jQuery slider

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which works perfectly fine, however I would like to add a play and stop button to it. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var slides = $(".slide").length;

   $("#slidesContainer").css("overflow", "hidden");

   (function () {
      for (i = 0; i < slides; i++) {
          var tabNumber = i + 1;
          $("#tabsstyle ul").append('<li><a href="#" rel="' + tabNumber + '"></a></li>')
      }
      $("#tabsstyle li a").bind("click", function () {
         $("#tabsstyle li a").removeClass("active");
         $(this).addClass("active");

         var tabNumber = "n" + $(this).attr("rel");
         $("div.slide").delay(200).fadeOut();
         $("#" + tabNumber).delay(200).fadeIn(600)
      })
   })()

   $('#tabsstyle ul li a:first').addClass('active'); // first tab selected on doucment ready    
});
```

Comment: Sure you can! But we need a demo of your example with HTML and all that stuff. Can you setup a http://jsbin.com ?

Comment: can you create a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsbin.com/upujif/3/edit#source there you go guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want is a way to start and stop a slideshow of your tabs. Here is one way. This is completely untested, but should get you in the right direction:

```
var intervalId;
function playTabs() {
    intervalId = setInterval("cycleTabs()", 1000);
}
function stopTabs() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}
function cycleTabs() {
    var currentTab = $("#tabsstyle li a.active");
    // Find the index number of the current tab by finding its position within its parent
    var currentTabNumber = $(currentTab).parent().children().index(currentTab);
    var nextTabNumber = currentTabNumber + 1;
    // if we are on the last slide then go back to the start
    if (currentTabNumber + 1 == slides) {
        nextTabNumber = 0;
    }
    $(currentTab).removeClass("active");
    $("div.slide").delay(200).fadeOut();
    $("#" + nextTabNumber).addClass("active");
    $("#" + nextTabNumber).delay(200).fadeIn(600)
}
```

Now just have your start/stop button call playTabs() or stopTabs() depending on what you want to do.

Comment: I will have a go at it thanks for your time to write this piece of code :)

Comment: HI David, What slides would be equal to?

Comment: I mean does it need to be declared first?

Comment: In my code it assumes that the slides variable is exactly what you already have in your code. So I was assuming that my code would be added to yours.

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ibehur/)*

You need only this simplified HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">

   <div id="slidesContainer">     
     <div class="slide"><h2>Slide-1</h2></div>      
     <div class="slide"><h2>Slide-2</h2></div>      
     <div class="slide"><h2>Slide-3</h2></div>  
     <div class="slide"><h2>Slide-4</h2></div>    
     <div class="slide"><h2>Slide-5</h2></div>   
     <div class="slide"><h2>Slide-6</h2></div>            
  </div>
  <div id="tabsstyle">
     <ul></ul>
     <div id="play_pause"></div>
  </div>
```

The added+modified CSS:

```
#tabsstyle li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
}

#tabsstyle li, #play_pause{
    color:#999;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#eee url(img/MenuIcon.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    display:block;
    width:35px;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:8px 0;
    margin: 0 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
}

#tabsstyle li.active{
    background:#cf5 url(img/MenuIcon.png) no-repeat 0 -35px;
}

#play_pause{
    position:absolute;
    line-height:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    right:0px;
}
```

The fun starts here:

```
var curr = 0;       // SET DESIRED START SLIDE
var delay = 2500;   // SET DELAY BETWEEN ANIMATIONS
var fadeTime = 700; // SET FADE TIME
var symb = [ '||' , '&#9658;' ]; // play-pause button symbols


// do not edit below this line :) //
var slides = $(".slide").length;
var inter;
    
$("#slidesContainer").css("overflow", "hidden");
$("#slidesContainer .slide").css('position','absolute').hide().eq(curr).show();


// CREATE BUTTONS /////////////////
for (i = 0; i < slides; i++){
    $("#tabsstyle ul").append('<li>'+(i+1)+'</li>');
}
$('#tabsstyle ul li').eq(curr).addClass('active'); // first tab selected on doucment ready   
// ////////////////////////////////


// OUR FUNCTIONS //////////////////  
function anim(){        
    $('#tabsstyle li').eq(curr).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active'); // Set active btn
    $('.slide').eq(curr).fadeIn(fadeTime).siblings().fadeOut(fadeTime); // Slides animation
}   
function stop(){
    clearInterval(interv);  // stop auto-animation
    interv = false;
    $("#play_pause").html( symb[1] );
}
function play(){
    interv = setInterval(function(){
        curr = (++curr % slides);
        anim();
    },delay+fadeTime);
    $("#play_pause").html( symb[0] );
}
// ///////////////////////////////

play(); // Start (at dom ready)
    
$("#tabsstyle").on("click", "li", function(){
    stop();                 // stop
    curr = $(this).index(); // set current slide
    anim();                 // Run 'anim' function to 'curr' slide
});
$("#play_pause").on("click", function(){
    var check= interv===false ? play() : stop();
});
```

Comment: nice one Roko, it seems like the auto play doesn't work well as it stops after one...

Comment: @Alex, I did not noticed that. Sorry. The code is bulletProof. There's something wrong with jsBin in 'fullsize', not with my code. As you can see in edit mode works fine, the script is error free and works in jsFiddle too. Tested locally also. You can download the demo and you will realize that it works flawlessly.  http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/SpU8E/

Comment: @Alex I did not mean nothing bad. *edited my comment* Take a look at the demo, download it , test it and let me know! If you have Q about the code just ask! Happy coding

Comment: Hi I just checked here http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/SpU8E/ and it works fine so that's really good thank you. Now I will go through the code which it looks more clean since I was using a unique ID for each slide to make it work

Comment: That's right! that's why i suggest the one above. Let me know if you have code-misunderstandings.